# SQL Server Generate Row from two range value

Tags: sql-server

I have one table which is call chqbook_tbl :

```
CBID   CBBankID      CBStartNo CBBookEndNo
1           1           1         5
2           1           21        25
3           2           1        5
```

And I have another table for chq_tbl as following

```
C_CBBankID     C_No    
    1            2     
    1           22
    2            1
    2            5
```

Now I need to select records get data as following:

```
C_BankID  C_No       C_Type
  1         1        Dynamic
  1         2        Static
  1         3        Dynamic
  1         4        Dynamic
  1         5        Dynamic
  1         21       Dynamic
  1         22       Static
  1         23       Dynamic
  1         24       Dynamic
  1         25       Dynamic
  2         1        Static
  2         2        Dynamic
  2         3        Dynamic
  2         4        Dynamic
  2         5        Static
```

Comment: Could you please explain, how the tables are connected and what logic is to be used to get the given output?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to join two columns and if so which two. What determines if the C_Type is Static or Dynamic?

Comment: @Shnugo: On chqbook_tbl I have a range for c_no for each CBBankID for example CBBankID 2 , I have 5 C_No from 1 to 5 on another table (chq_tbl) I have some records now first I need select c_no from CBBankID then except records from CBBankID and add CBBankID  records.

Comment: @JosephGagliardo : Dynamic records which is not in chq_tbl and dynamic is selected row from range(CBStartNo to CBBookEndNo) of c_no

Comment: Sorry I am trying to help you but I still have no idea of what your business logic is.

Comment: @JosephGagliardo : See first I need to select records from chqbook_tbl based on StartNo & EndNo for each CBBankID , for example result will like this:
C_BankID  C_No       C_Type
  1         1        Dynamic
  1         2        Dynamic
  1         3        Dynamic
  1         4        Dynamic
  1         5        Dynamic
  1         21       Dynamic
  1         22       Dynamic
  1         23       Dynamic
  1         24       Dynamic
  1         25       Dynamic

Then I need to replace records from chq_tbl which is match in Result table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a numbers table (like `master..spt_values`) to get all the number in the ranges specified by `CBStartNo` and `CBBookEndNo` and then left join `chq_tbl` and use a case expression to set the Dynamic/Static attribute depending on null values.

This should work:

```
select 
    c1.CBBankID, 
    m.Number as C_No, 
    case when c2.C_No is null then 'Dynamic' else 'Static' end as C_Type
from master..spt_values m
join chqbook_tbl c1 on m.number between c1.CBStartNo and c1.CBBookEndNo
left join chq_tbl c2 on m.number = c2.C_No and c1.CBBankID = c2.C_CBBankID
where m.type = 'P'
```

Note that the numbers table I used only holds values 0-2047 so if you need higher numbers you should either construct a suitable table or use a recursive query to generate the numbers on the fly.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59ec5/2)

Answer (score 3):

Using a Tally Table, you can generate the `C_No`s between `CBStartNo` and `CBBookEnd`. Then do a `LEFT JOIN` on `chq_tbl` to determine if the row is Static or Dynamic.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/471f4/1/0)

```
WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT MAX(CBBookEndNo) FROM chqbook_tbl)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
)
SELECT
    C_BankID = cb.CBBankID,
    C_No = t.N,
    C_Ttype = CASE WHEN ct.C_No IS NULL THEN 'Dynamic' ELSE 'Static' END
FROM chqbook_tbl cb
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT N
    FROM Tally
    WHERE N BETWEEN cb.CBStartNo AND cb.CBBookEndNo
)t
LEFT JOIN chq_tbl ct
    ON ct.CBBankID = cb.CBBankID
    AND ct.C_No = t.N
```